# How to get the Log In Form on every page? (for example in footer) Typo3

Tags: forms, typo3, felogin

Is there a way to get the Log In Form for Frontend User on every page? I would prefer the footer.
And if someone is logged in you can see the Log Out Button.
Is this possible without an extension?

Comment: Which TYPO3 version? (I would like to add it to the tags.)

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the default `felogin` output to wherever you want on your template. For example use `lib.login`, copy the `plugin.tx_felogin_pi1` into it, change the template and you're fine.

```
lib.login < plugin.tx_felogin_pi1
lib.login.templateFile = path/to/your/template/file
```

More you can see in the official documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/felogin/8.7/Configuration/Index.html

Comment: what do you mean by path to template file? I have been using the backend before. I've added a login form to every sub page. Now I'm trying to do it the right way. So I guess your code belongs in a typoscript template? But I don't think you're referring to that typoscript template or are you?

Answer (score 0):

In general there are three options to include a CE (e.g. the Login-form) on all pages:

1. use typoscript to generate the CE. Normally the CEs are defined in `tt_content`, from where you could copy the base configuration and adapt it. For some plugins you also find a complete configuration beyond `lib` (for newer extensions there you only find the settings). All the configuration must be done in typoscript.
2. use typoscript to render the content of a special page/ column. In this variant you have a special page only for content referenced somewhere else. Advantage: you could configure the CE in the usual way. Try to avoid referencing CEs by uid as an editor might disable or delete the current element(s) and insert a new one which would not be rendered.
3. use a special column in your root page and inherit the content to all subpages. Advantage: you could change the inherited content easily on each page (if this column is available in the current backend layout).

example for 3:

```
variables {  
    footer_content < styles.content.get
    footer_content.select.where = colPos = 15
    footer_content.slide = -1
}
```